# My query doesn't work anymore when I remove a primary key

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating my database  with primary key i am passing this primary key to another  table suppose, now i am deleting primary key my query is not fetching the value because i am using join to retrieve the data what is solution for that because this primary id is missing in the reference table in php mysql.

**community table :**

```
 c.d_id    communityname
   1          BC
   2          SC
   3          ST
```

**student Table**

```
  ID           Community
   1             1
   2             3
   3             1
```

**SQL**

```
SELECT c.communityname FROM student  s left join community c on c.d_id=s.community WHERE s.stud_rollno = '".$rollno."' GROUP BY stud_rollno
```

Comment: Please use the formatting machi!

Comment: I think it's unclear what you're asking. Also, in the absence of any aggregating fucntions, your use of GROUP BY is inappropriate and (potentially) misleading.

Comment: leave group not required for the requirement, the primary key is passing in next table, based on those id i am showing community name, now the primary key was deleted the query not displayed the result what is  the solution for this sir

Comment: kinldy help me i don't how to use this situation

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **LEFT Join**, you can use a simple **Sub Query** with a **`WHERE`** clause da!

```
SELECT `id`, (
  SELECT `communityname` FROM `community` WHERE `Community`=`d_id`
) FROM `student`;
```

Else you need to cascade the primary keys and foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your problem right, you are using a primary key as an attribute in another table, it is a foreign key for that new table.

By specifying this, you can use cascade behaviors to remove "foreign rows" when the primary key is deleted in the first table.

```
CONSTRAINT fk_column
   FOREIGN KEY (column1, column2, ... column_n)
   REFERENCES parent_table (column1, column2, ... column_n)
   ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about this is to update the student table with another Community ID that exists in the Community table, delete the student with the ON DELETE CASCADE.

Comment: I got your way but again the id was changing on student table then how can retrieve based on id, another way is shall i remove the delete option in form for community table

Comment: Before deleting the c.d_id from the community table, run an update on the student table (and any other tables). When a record has the community id that you want to delete, update it with a different c.d_id, then delete the record from the community table. Make sure you are not confusing the two ID's in your query.
`UPDATE student SET communityid = 2 WHERE communityid = 1;`
`DELETE FROM community WHERE communityid = 1;`

Comment: As your suggestion it is not matching with the same id, assume 1=BC , 2=SC, after deleting 1 in community table if i update to student table means it takes second id now the both id is different.  What shall we do ?.